# Trimming the filename using _ and removing characters using python

Tags: python-3.x

If my file name is 5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843_20200616T10_50_UTC.wav .. Output to be 5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843.wav . How can we trim the file name using python?

Comment: why not 5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843.wav ? what is the rule, to remove all from the second '_' up to '.' (excluded) ?

Comment: @bruno Sorry, updated the ask.. You are right with the output..

Comment: so, there are several ways to do, no idea at all ?

Comment: I tried with rsplit .. filename1 = (filename + '_').rsplit('_', 1)[1]  But not getting the desired output

Comment: warning, may be there is a `_` in your remark, but it was removed by formater, place your code between ` (backquote)

Comment: `filename = 5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843_20200616T10_50_UTC.wav`
`filename1 = (filename + '_').rsplit('_', 1)[1]`

Comment: I put a proposal, not sure is the 'best' because my low level in python, but it works both in python 2 and 3

Comment: @bruno Thanks it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do, for instance

```
import os

l=os.path.splitext("5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843_20200616T10_50_UTC.wav")
l[0].split("_")[0] + l[1]
```

I use `os.path.splitext` to separate the possible extension

Execution with and without '_' and with and without extension :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> def f(s):
...   l = os.path.splitext(s)
...   return l[0].split("_")[0] + l[1]
... 
>>> f("5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843_20200616T10_50_UTC.wav")
'5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843.wav'
>>> 
>>> f("5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843.wav")
'5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843.wav'
>>> 
>>> f("5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843_20200616T10_50_UTC")
'5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843'
>>> 
>>> f("5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843")
'5f0756fa-75bc-4c70-9ba8-fbd1b6a9f843'
>>>
```